# bash command variable creation

Tags: variable, command, variable-substitution

I have this command that I've created and would like to place it in a variable.

```
sort -k 1,1 | tr " " "\n" | users | wc -l
```

Such as the one below, however, as of now the output produces an error and does not work correctly

```
us_num=$(users | tr " " "\n" | sort -k 1,1 | wc -l)
echo "Currently there is $(us_num) number of users on the server."
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You are using `$(us_num)` to dereference the variable `us_num`. However, as you can see from your own example, this is the syntax for a _command substitution_, which means it tries to _execute_ the result of the previous call to `users | tr ... | wc -l` as a command and return the result. This can only produce an error (btw. please alway include error messages you get in your questions to make it easier to point you to the problem). The correct syntax for using the variable's value is `$us_num`. The shell syntax is different from the Makefile syntax in that respect.

Comment: The `sort` is redundant here. You might as well do `users | wc -w` here or `who | wc -l` so it works for usernames that contain spaces.

Comment: this was the original                                                                               echo "The current number of users logged into"
echo "the server at this time are"
users |tr " " "\n" |sort -k 1,1 | wc -w
 and was looking for a shorter version with variables    thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

`$(us_num)` is a command substitution that will run the command `us_num` and which will be replaced by the output of that command.

To insert the value of the *variable* `us_num`, use `$us_num` instead:

```
printf 'There are currently %d number of users on the server\n' "$us_num"
```

Also note that the first pipeline that you mention has its commands place out of order.  The `users` command would ignore the input from `tr`, and `sort` would wait for input from the terminal.

As mentioned in comments, you may also make the pipeline shorter through using `wc -w` (which counts words):

```
printf 'There are currently %d number of users on the server\n' "$(users|wc -w)"
```